# What is the easy way for extracting a dted raster file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, extract-by-mask

I have some SRTM data which was converted to dted file with GlobalMapper or ArcMap ascii to raster. I want to extract raster from vector with an easy way. I have tried "extract by mask" method but it depends raster files for i/o.

Do you know any easy way of extracting a raster?

A section is raster file B section is vector file.

**B section is what i want to extract from A Raster File.**

**Raster File:**

[image]

**Raster and Vector File:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcGis 10 you can use the [Clip (data management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000009n000000) tool to do what you ask for. In the input options, you can specify the `clipping_geometry` option to clip the input raster to a polygon.

Comment: thank you. with checking "Use Input Features for Clipping Geometry(optional)" solves the problem... and Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > Extract by Mask option is another alternative....